# Integrity verification has failed

Tags: samsung

Hi my Samsung J7 Prime just stuck on The integrity verification has failed. You need to reset your device to factory default settings. This will erase your data. i dont want to reset the phone because my data is important on the phone please help me what to do without losing the data ?? please please please

Comment: descripe what actions you did to get integrity verification failed

Answer (score 1):

I really hate to be the bearer of bad news, but if you have an integrity failure, you probably wouldn't want to boot your device even if you could.

Allow me to explain. The "integrity failed" message means that a part of your system has been modified and might not be safe to boot. It might have been modified by a malicious app, program, or it could have just been you trying to root your device. (If it's the last one, please make sure you follow all directions by whatever guide you are using to root your device in order to make sure that stuff like this doesn't happen).

Unfortunately, what this means for you is you are going to have to reset your device. It is a security feature built into android, so it's best you follow it's direction. I know how this feels, it sucks, but its just the case with this error. Make sure in the future that you keep backups of any important data.

If you don't read any other part of this answer, please read this:

**If you reset your device and the error continues, STOP! Unless you know what you are doing, this error can be very difficult to correct on your own, and easy to make worse for yourself. Instead, take your phone into a repair shop or your carrier to have them fix it.**

If I'm completely getting your situation wrong, please let me know any additional information you have and I will try to update my answer accordingly. Best of luck to you.

Comment: it may possible to fix without erasing userdata. usually official stock ROM can be flashed with glass echidna heimdall or odin. maybe the device is already rooted and it just requires disable dm-verity. but @KazimAhmed didn't tell us the reason for integrity fail, so it's all speculation

Comment: Yeah the answer I gave was assuming he has no idea what caused it.